# Simple Proof over integers and rational numbers.

Tags: integers, rational-numbers

I'm sure this is a relatively easy thing to do, I'm just not sure how to begin.

Here I wish to show that if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that
$$
\frac{3}{2} \pm k \not \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Or, to extend, if $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{p}{q} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$ that
$$
\frac{p}{q} - k \not \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Not asking for a full solution, just a starting point.

Thank you!

Comment: why that should be simple... $\frac{3}{2} \pm k = \frac{3 \pm 2k}{2}$, where the numerator is odd..

Comment: If $\tfrac pq-k=n$ is an integer, then $\tfrac pq=k+n$ is also an integer, because the sum of any two integers is an integer. But that contradicts $\tfrac pq\not\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore $\tfrac pq-k$ is not an integer. (Also note that the $\pm$ sign is irrelevant, because the opposite of an integer is also an integer.)

Comment: @mr_e_man - Thank you! If you post as a an answer, I will mark as the solution. Thanks again!